# JSON.stringify only key value

Tags: javascript

I want to compare a object with a string. To do so I JSON.stringify the object(date). How can I extract the value only? I could splice the result but thought about a faster solution. Any other possibilites how to get `"10.09.2021"` out of  `{"date":"10.09.2021"}`?

```js
 var graph = {
            "nodes": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "dates": [
                        {
                            "date": "10.09.2021"
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "12.10.2021"
                        }
                    ]
                }, {
                    "id": 2,
                    "dates": [
                        {
                            "date": "20.09.2021"
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "25.09.2021"
                        }
                    ]
                }, {
                    "id": 3,
                    "dates": [
                        {
                            "date": "07.10.2021"
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "12.10.2021"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
       }
              
graph.nodes.forEach(element => {
  element.dates.forEach(date => {
    strDate = JSON.stringify(date)
    console.log(strDate) // {"date":"dd.mm.yyyy"}
    
//how to extract "dd.mm.yyyy" only?
    
    if (strDate === "12.10.2021") {
      console.log("true")
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: `graph.nodes[0].dates[0].date`

Comment: Just `strDate = date.date`, without stringifying.

Comment: You can change `date` in element.dates.forEach to `({strDate})` to get the date property. No need to stringify  (or just do strDate = date.date )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to use stringify at all. just address it as regular object.

```js
var graph = {
            "nodes": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "dates": [
                        {
                            "date": "10.09.2021"
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "12.10.2021"
                        }
                    ]
                }, {
                    "id": 2,
                    "dates": [
                        {
                            "date": "20.09.2021"
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "25.09.2021"
                        }
                    ]
                }, {
                    "id": 3,
                    "dates": [
                        {
                            "date": "07.10.2021"
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "12.10.2021"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
       }
              
graph.nodes.forEach(element => {
  element.dates.forEach(date => {
    strDate = date.date;
    console.log(date.date) // {"date":"dd.mm.yyyy"}
    
//how to extract "dd.mm.yyyy" only?
    
    if (strDate === "12.10.2021") {
      console.log("true")
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

In stringify you just have to access the key of date object recieved in forEach. Please see below code
strDate = JSON.stringify(date.date) or strDate = JSON.stringify(date['date'])